# Client to use the slave when the master is down in MySQL replication

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-workbench, mysql-5.1

Is it possible for the client to use the slave when the master is down in mysql replication?

I have already setup a simple mysql replication having a master and a slave.

The client connects to the master to access the database, any changes made to the master server is replication onto the slave. How shall I configure that when the master server is down, the client automatically connects to the slave server?

I am using MySQL Server 5.1 and MySQL workbench 5.2 CE. I edited the my.ini files for both master and slave.

The client uses a J2EE application.

What additional commands must I input in the master my.ini file to make the changes?

Also is there a way to increase or decrease the time interval between replications?

Comment: Hi Dwayne. Welcome to the site! Is it possible to expand the second aspect of your question into it's own question? "Also is there a way to increase or decrease the time interval between replications?" We like to keep questions as one question per thread.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have Master/Slave, you may want to implement the use of two things

1. Circular Replication
2. Database Virtual IP (aka DBVIP)

## **Circular Replication**

Circular Replication is nothing more than first setting up Master/Slave then performing the same steps using the Slave as the Master's Master and the Master as the Slave's Slave. It just entails

- explicitly user a different server_id on each DB Server
- enabling binary logging on both DB servers
- making sure the replication user is defined on both DB servers

## **Database Virtual IP (aka DBVIP)**

There are products you can download and install to setup a DBVIP. One such product I use is [`ucarp`](http://www.ucarp.org/project/ucarp). Another product is Linux Heartbeat. I normally do not use such things with MySQL Circular Replication or Master/Slave. Why?

Since those products can perform automatic failover, you do not want to do that in the event a Slave is some number of seconds behind in replication lag.

You should perform manual failovers.

Here is a poor man's approach to implementing DBVIP management.

Suppose you have this setup

- DB Server1 has IP 10.1.2.30
- DB Server2 has IP 10.1.2.40
- You want to use DBVIP 10.1.2.50

Create the Script called /usr/local/sbin/MyAppDBVIP like this

```
echo echo 10.1.2.50 > /usr/local/sbin/MyAppDBVIP
```

Create the Script called /usr/local/sbin/dbvip-up

```
DBVIP=`/usr/local/sbin/MyAppDBVIP`
ip addr add ${DBVIP}/24 dev eth1
```

Create the Script called /usr/local/sbin/dbvip-down

```
DBVIP=`/usr/local/sbin/MyAppDBVIP`
ip addr del ${DBVIP}/24 dev eth1
```

Make sure all scripts are executable

```
chmod +x /usr/local/sbin/MyAppDBVIP
chmod +x /usr/local/sbin/dbvip-up
chmod +x /usr/local/sbin/dbvip-down
```

Make sure these script exist on both DB Servers

Simply run dbvip on whichever server you choose. .

So the failover process and protocol are the following:

- Run `dbvip-down` on the DB Server that has the DBVIP. If you cannot
- Run `dbvip-up` on the DB Server that you want to have the DBVIP
- Just remember you should not run `dbvip-up` on both machines
- After running `dbvip-up`, restart apache, JBoss, or any other app server contacting MySQL via the old Master

Answer (score 1):

In what way do you mean 'to use the slave when the master is down'? When the master goes down, the process of switching the slave to become the master is what we call 'failover'.

But once your application starts using the old slave in this failover scenario, it becomes the new master. When you get the old master online again it must be set up as a slave, because your data has changed.

Failover for your situation (a single slave) is going to be mainly handled in your application. You will need to implement logic to check that the application is connecting. If it is not, have the application connect to the slave instead.

A few things to keep in mind:

- Again, once your application connects to the slave and modifies data, you need to ensure it never tries to connect to the master again.
- You will probably want to have some alert monitoring setup (using Nagios or some other suite), so you know when the master fails.